# How To Make A Loop Using v-for With Condition "Like Forelse" In Laravel Framework

Tags: vue.js

I'm Just Trying To Do Something using Vue Similar To forelse in *laravel framework blade*,
This Is Just To Do a Test To Confirm If Table Has Records Or Not, If No, It Allows Me To Add A Default Value Like :

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">There's No Records Yet</td>
</tr>
```

I Tried This But It Gives Me `[vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for]`

```html
<tr v-for="(category, index) in this.categories" :key="index" v-if="categories">
    <td>{{ category.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
    <td style="width: 20%;">
        <img :src="`${$store.state.baseUrl}/storage/${category.image}`" style="width: 100%;" :alt="category.name">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteCategory(category)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr v-else>
    <th colspan="4" class="text-center">There's No Reacoards Yet</th>
</tr>
```

Is There Anyone Has A Solution For This Issue, 
Thank You 
- Muhammed Elfeqy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the times where you want to use the invisible [`<template>` element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt)

For example

```html
<template v-if="categories.length > 0">
  <tr v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
    <!-- and so on -->
  </tr>
</template>
<tr v-else>
  <td colspan="4">There's No Records Yet</td>
</tr>
```